# Trying to build accountants calculators but javascript doesn't work on safari/firefox

Tags: javascript, browser, safari

I have been working on some code for some calculators for an accountant. It seems to work fine in Internet Explorer: you type in the figures and it adds it all up, but in Safari and Firefox it is as if the JavaScript file hasn't been recognized and just scrolls up to the top of the page.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

JavaScript:

```
function Calculation()
{
var error_flag = false;
var error_string = "";

if (isNaN(document.calcfuel.mileage.value))
    {
    error_flag = true
    error_string = error_string + "Non numeric mileage.\n"
    }

if (isNaN(document.calcfuel.mpg.value))
    {
    error_flag = true
    error_string = error_string + "Non numeric miles per gallon.\n"
    }

if (isNaN(document.calcfuel.fuelprice.value))
    {
    error_flag = true
    error_string = error_string + "Non numeric fuel price.\n"
    }

if (error_flag)
    alert(error_string);
else
    {
    var fuelcost = ((document.calcfuel.mileage.value / document.calcfuel.mpg.value) * 4.54 * document.calcfuel.fuelprice.value) / 100;
    fuelcost = (parseInt(fuelcost * 100)) / 100;

    if (isNaN(fuelcost))
        {
        error_string = "Incorrect data entered\n";
        alert(error_string);
        }
    else
        {
        document.calcfuel.output_value.value=fuelcost;
        return false;
        }
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" class="pageCalcPFuelcost" lang="en" xml:lang="en" id="sharedContentCalculators">
<head>
<script src="C:\Users\Faye\Desktop\calcs\calcs\fuel_cost.js" type="text/javascript">
</script>
<div id="calculator">
<form name="calcfuel" id="calcfuel">

<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="428" class="bgColorContent">
    <tr>
        <td class="cornerTopLeft"><img src="/images/spacer.gif" alt="" width="8" height="32" border="0" /></td>
        <td class="bgTop">How much do you spend on fuel in a year?</td>
        <td class="cornerTopRight"><img src="/images/spacer.gif" alt="" width="8" height="32" border="0" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="bgLeft"><img src="/images/spacer.gif" alt="" width="8" height="1" border="0" /></td>
        <td class="bgColorContent"><br /><strong>With the fluctuating cost of fuel seemingly an ever-present news item, we thought that using our fuel cost calculator would show how much you are now spending on fuel.<br /><br /> Enter the number of miles you expect to drive in the next twelve months, the cost of fuel, less <acronym title="Value Added Tax">VAT</acronym> if you are <acronym title="Value Added Tax">VAT</acronym> registered and the mpg for your vehicle.</strong></td>
        <td class="bgRight"><img src="/images/spacer.gif" alt="" width="8" height="1" border="0" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="bgLeft"><img src="/images/spacer.gif" alt="" width="8" height="1" border="0" /></td>
        <td class="bgColorContent">
            <table align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="5" border="0" width="360">
                <tr> 
                    <td align="right" class="bgColorContent">


<tr>
    <td class="borderhorizontal" colspan="2"><img src="/images/spacer.gif" alt="" width="1" height="1" border="0" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="bgColorContent" colspan="2"><img src="/images/spacer.gif" alt="" width="1" height="5" border="0" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="bgColorContent" align="right"><label for="miles">Enter the number of miles per year you drive :</label></td>
    <td class="bgColorContent"><input type="text" class="form" id="miles" name="mileage" value="12000" size="10" maxlength="6"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td class="bgColorContent" align="right"><label for="price_litre">Enter your normal price for a litre of fuel in pence:</label></td>
    <td class="bgColorContent" align="right" valign="bottom"><input type="text" class="form" id="price_litre" name="fuelprice" value="135" size="10" /></td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td class="bgColorContent" align="right"><label for="mpg">Enter the <acronym title="Miles per Gallon">MPG</acronym> you average in your vehicle :</label></td>
    <td class="bgColorContent"><input type="text" id="mpg" class="form" name="mpg" value="35" size="10" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="bgColorContent" colspan="2"><img src="/images/spacer.gif" alt="" width="1" height="5" border="0" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="2" align="right" class="bgColorContent"><input class="button" type="reset" name="Reset" value="Reset" />&nbsp;&nbsp;<input class="button" type="button" name="Calculate" value="Calculate" OnClick="Calculation()">
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="bgColorContent" colspan="2"><img src="/images/spacer.gif" alt="" width="1" height="5" border="0" /></td>
</tr>
<tr> 
    <td align="right" class="bgColorContent"><strong><label for="todays_money">Fuel expenditure per year </label></strong></td>
    <td align="right" valign="bottom" class="bgColorContent"><input type="text" id="todays_money" name="output_value" size="10" class="form" /></td>
</tr>



<tr>
    <td class="bgColorContent" colspan="2"><img src="/images/spacer.gif" alt="" width="1" height="5" border="0" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="borderhorizontal" colspan="2"><img src="/images/spacer.gif" alt="" width="1" height="1" border="0" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="bgColorContent" colspan="2"><img src="/images/spacer.gif" alt="" width="1" height="5" border="0" /></td>
</tr>
</table>

    </td>
        <td class="bgRight"><img src="/images/spacer.gif" alt="" width="8" height="1" border="0" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="bgLeft"><img src="/images/spacer.gif" alt="" width="8" height="1" border="0" /></td>
        <td class="bgColorContent"><span class="sharedCalculatorsClassToHideText">You may be interested in <a href="/content/padvisor_home/keeping_fuel_costs_down.html">viewing our ideas</a> for keeping your fuel costs down.</a></span></td>
        <td class="bgRight"><img src="/images/spacer.gif" alt="" width="8" height="1" border="0" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="cornerBottomLeft"><img src="/images/spacer.gif" alt="" width="8" height="8" border="0" /></td>
        <td class="bgBottom"><img src="/images/spacer.gif" alt="" height="1" border="0" /></td>
        <td class="cornerBottomRight"><img src="/images/spacer.gif" alt="" width="8" height="8" border="0" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>

</form>

<br />


</div>


</div>
```

Comment: `fuelcost = (parseInt(fuelcost * 100)) / 100;` Why is that??

Answer (score 0):

Instead of document.form.element try using document.getElementById('id-of-the-input-element') to access the DOM element.

Answer (score 0):

Validate your html for that list of errors. Never, ever use IE as a reference for how things should work. Always, always check in a modern browser first.